# Inherit common functions in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, coding-style, private-methods

I want to create many Service classes that use a common set of functions. All these classes will inherit ClientBase class which is provided by Microsoft. Currently I have written those common functionalities as private methods in class. What is the best way to do it to avoid code repetition and efficiency. I cannot add those common methods to base class as it cannot be modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have your own abstract base class that inherits `ClientBase<T>`, call it `MyClientBase<T>`, move the common methods to it and make them protected so that successors could access them. Then make your service classes inherit `MyClientBase<T>`.

Comment: I am implementing it like `public abstract class WingsClientBase<T>:ClientBase<T> where T :class` Is it acceptable, since ClientBase take an interface and I am writing `where T:class` in definition. I get compiler error **Compiler Error CS0452 - MSDN - Microsoft** without writing `where T:class`

Comment: This error occurs when you pass a value type such as a struct or int as a parameter to a generic type or method that has a reference type constraint. Get rid of `where T:class` constraint or don't use it with value types.

Answer (score 0):

If all other classes are directly inheriting from `ClientBase<T>`I would try to define the additional functionalities via extension methods of `ClientBase<T>`.